# Transpose and combine grouped data to more linear format

Tags: charts, google-sheets, transpose

Although this must be a common thing, I'm wracking my head on how to convert data from the following:

```
          jan | feb | mar  
year 1 |   1     2     3
year 2 |   4     5     6
```

To something like:

```
     date        value
jan/31/year1   |   1
feb/28/year1   |   2
mar/31/year1   |   3
jan/31/year2   |   4
feb/28/year2   |   5
mar/31/year2   |   6
```

To ultimately be able to produce a line chart over time.

Comment: Google Sheets and Excel have some similar features but other are very different. Are you looking for something that works on both? What do you thing that could work? If you think that this something common, do you tried to find a question about this on this site before posting one new question?

Comment: Looking for Google Sheets features. I did try searching for other similar questions but haven't found what I'm specifically looking for. Obviously, I can manually transpose, concat, copy, paste, repeat, but surely there must be a more elegant solution to what I feel is a common manipulation.

Comment: Yes, it's a common manipulation. Here are some keywords: unpivot, normalization, simple-table. By the way, the details about what you tried or think that could be part of the solution should be included in the question itself. Please [edit] it to add those details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `1` is in E2 and headers have been added to A1 and B1.

In A2:

```
=lower(TEXT(EOMONTH("1/1/17",row()-2),"mmm/"))&left(eomonth("1/1/17",row()-2),2)&"/year "&roundup((row()-1)/12)
```

in B2:

```
=INDEX(E$2:P,MATCH(right(A2,6),D$2:D$7,0),MATCH(left(A2,3),E$1:P$1,0))
```

Both copied down to suit.

The two way lookup (ColumnB) is indeed a *common thing* but I dispute that the ColumnA format is.